# Your Query does not include the specified expression "ID" as part of an aggregate function. MS acces

Tags: ms-access

Hi dear developer friends, I am trying the following code but I am getting this error : Your Query does not include the specified expression "ID" as part of an aggregate function.

The code is

```
SELECT ID, Date, Time, Status, BoxType, Material, Rack, EmployeeNr, Transaction FROM Records 
WHERE Transaction<100 AND ID NOT IN 
(SELECT `ID` FROM Records a WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT `ID` FROM records b WHERE b.Transaction>100 AND (b.Date=a.Date) AND (b.Time > a.Time) AND (b.Transaction-100=a.Transaction))) 
UNION 
SELECT ID, Date, Time, Status, BoxType, Material, Rack, EmployeeNr, Transaction FROM records a WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT `ID` FROM records b WHERE b.Transaction>100 AND (b.date=a.date) AND (b.time > a.time) AND (b.Transaction-100=a.Transaction)) 
GROUP BY Transaction 
HAVING COUNT(Transaction)>1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are both grouping by and counting Transaction which doesn't make much sense.

If counting on one field, the remaining must be grouped by or aggregated somehow. Also, reserved words must be bracketed (Status and Transaction may need as well), and you would not pull the string `"ID"` but instead the field from the subqueries.

So, as we have no idea what you are trying to achieve, no direct solution is possible, but this should get you started:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, [Date], [Time], Status, BoxType, Material, Rack, EmployeeNr, Transaction 
FROM 
    Records 
WHERE 
    Transaction < 100 AND ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM Records a WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT ID FROM Records b WHERE 
        b.Transaction>100 AND (b.Date=a.Date) AND (b.Time > a.Time) AND (b.Transaction-100=a.Transaction))) 
UNION 
SELECT 
    ID, [Date], [Time], Status, BoxType, Material, Rack, EmployeeNr, Transaction 
FROM 
    Records a 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT ID FROM Records b WHERE 
        b.Transaction>100 AND (b.date=a.date) AND (b.time > a.time) AND (b.Transaction-100=a.Transaction)) 
GROUP BY 
    ID, [Date], [Time], Status, BoxType, Material, Rack, EmployeeNr, Transaction 
HAVING 
    COUNT(Transaction) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! However, I want to Group by only Transaction.  'GROUP BY Transaction', If I do this, I will receive the same error.

Comment: OK. Then you must decide what to do with each of the remaining fields: Exclude, group by, or aggregate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Gustav! I appreciate !  :)